# Como popular um select de acordo com o select anterior pegando dados do banco de dados?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Então galera, eu estou tentando criar dois selects sendo que um carrega as especialidades de medicos gravadas em uma tabela no banco e o outro mostra os medicos de acordo com cada especialidade marcada, eu ja estou conseguindo colocar os dados das especialidades no primeiro select como podem ver aqui:

```
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
                                
    <label>Especialidades</label>
    <select name="Especialidades_idEsp" id="Especialidades_idEsp" class="form-control"  required>
      <option value="">Escolha a Especialidade</option>
          <?php
                                        
                                                      $result_esp = "SELECT * FROM  especialidades ORDER BY nome_especialidade";
                                                      $resultado_esp = mysqli_query($conexao, $result_esp);
                                                      while($row_esp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_esp)){
                                                        echo '<option value="'.$row_esp['idEsp'].'">'.$row_esp['nome_especialidade'].'</option>';
                                                      }
                                                      
                                        ?>
                                      </select> 
                                    </div>
```

essa aqui é minha conexão com o banco:`<?php

$severname = "localhost";
$database = "clinicalsys";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
//agora se cria a conexão abaixo
$conexao = mysqli_connect($severname, $username, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>`

aqui tem o meu arquivo que pega os dados dos nomes dos medicos do banco de dados e compara com a especialidade :

```
<?php 

    include 'conexao.php' ;

$Especialidades_idEsp = $_REQUEST['Especialidades_idEsp'];

$result_med = "SELECT * FROM medico WHERE Especialidades_idEsp=$idEsp ORDER BY nome";
$resultado_med = mysqli_query($conexao, $result_med);

while ($row_med = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_med) ) {
    $medicos_post[] = array(
        'idMedico'  => $row_med['idMedico'],
        'nome' => utf8_encode($row_med['nome']),
    );
}

echo(json_encode($medicos_post));
```

?>

esse aqui é meu script em javascript pra tentar mostrar no outro select os nome dos medicos

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#Especialidades_idEsp').change(function(){
            if( $(this).val() ) {
                $('#idMedico').hide();
                $('.carregando').show();
                $.getJSON('post_medicos.php?search=',{Especialidades_idEsp: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
                    var options = '<option value="">Escolha o Médico</option>'; 
                    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                        options += '<option value="' + j[i].idMedico + '">' + j[i].medicos_post + '</option>';
                    }   
                    $('#idMedico').html(options).show();
                    $('.carregando').hide();
                });
            } else {
                $('#idMedico').html('<option value="">– Escolha o Medico –</option>');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

e por fim o segundo select:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 ">
                                        <label>Médicos</label>
                                        <span class="carregando">Aguarde, Carregando..</span>
                                        <select name="idMedico" id="idMedico "class="form-control" required>
                                        
                                        
                                      </select> 
                                    </div>
```

sei que ficou grande mas alguem poderia me ajudar ? nao consigo consertar

Comment: seria recomendado criar uma função que recebesse uma consulta (query) a ser enviada para o banco e retornasse os dados solicitados de acordo com a consulta (função que recebe a consulta em `String` e devolve o resultado em `Array`). Desta forma, você pode no PHP, ou JavaScript, tanto optar pelo uso do JSON ou pela leitura de matrizes associativas, o que ficaria menos trabalhoso e mais eficiente para a resolução do problema.